# joomla 1.5.22 on mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, joomla, types

I have fond some tutorials about joomla instalation on mysql 5.5, and i did everything 
(changed all "TYPE=MyISAM" to "ENGINE=MyISAM" in sql files in \installation\sql\mysql), and joomla 1.5.22 installed fine. But when i opened my home page `http://localhost/joomla` (usning xampp) i saw a lot if errors:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 29

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 32

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::clean() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 33

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 463

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 464

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 465

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 466

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 467

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanArray() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 468

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 35

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 71



Strict Standards: Non-static method JModuleHelper::_load() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php on line 88

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::getBool() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php on line 97

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::getVar() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 217

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanVar() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 151

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFilterInput::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 577

Strict Standards: Non-static method JUtility::parseAttributes() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\document\html\html.php on line 382

Strict Standards: Non-static method JModuleHelper::getModules() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer\modules.php on line 40

Strict Standards: Non-static method JModuleHelper::_load() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php on line 88

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::getBool() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php on line 97

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::getVar() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 217

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanVar() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 151

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFilterInput::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 577

Strict Standards: Non-static method JUtility::parseAttributes() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\document\html\html.php on line 382

Strict Standards: Non-static method JModuleHelper::getModules() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer\modules.php on line 40

Strict Standards: Non-static method JModuleHelper::_load() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php on line 88

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::getBool() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php on line 97

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::getVar() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 217

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanVar() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 151

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFilterInput::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 577

Strict Standards: Non-static method JUtility::parseAttributes() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\document\html\html.php on line 382

Strict Standards: Non-static method JModuleHelper::getModules() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer\modules.php on line 40

Strict Standards: Non-static method JModuleHelper::_load() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php on line 88

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::getBool() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php on line 97

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::getVar() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 217

Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::_cleanVar() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 151

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFilterInput::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\request.php on line 577

Strict Standards: Non-static method JUtility::parseAttributes() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\document\html\html.php on line 382

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::setHeader() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\document\document.php on line 776

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::setHeader() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\document\document.php on line 780

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::setBody() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\includes\application.php on line 169

Strict Standards: Non-static method JDispatcher::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\application\application.php on line 499

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getApplication() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\plugins\system\sef.php on line 47

Strict Standards: Non-static method JURI::base() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\plugins\system\sef.php on line 54

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::getBody() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\plugins\system\sef.php on line 55

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getEditor() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\plugins\system\sef.php on line 58

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 71

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getConfig() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 383

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 161

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 138

Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\loader.php on line 186

Strict Standards: Non-static method JEditor::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\factory.php on line 387

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::setBody() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\plugins\system\sef.php on line 104

Strict Standards: Non-static method JFactory::getConfig() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\application\application.php on line 382

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::toString() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\index.php on line 88

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::getBody() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\response.php on line 190

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::allowCache() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\response.php on line 197

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::setHeader() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\response.php on line 199

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::setHeader() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\response.php on line 200

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::setHeader() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\response.php on line 201

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::setHeader() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\response.php on line 202

Strict Standards: Non-static method JResponse::sendHeaders() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla2\libraries\joomla\environment\response.php on line 205
```

that is not all, stackoverflow showed: "body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 99377" :D

i donwloaded another copy of joomla 1.5.22 from joomla.org but without result. so please help me!!!!!!!! i think that there must be cnaged something but i don't know exactly what.

Comment: Those are warnings/notes, not errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logged (and displayed, if `display_errors` is on) *Strict Standards* messages are recommendations logged by the PHP interpreter, if your log level (error_reporting level) includes the `E_STRICT` mode.

To disable them, check your PHP configuration file (*php.ini*) for the `error_reporting` setting.

If you have `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT` you want to change it to `error_reporting = E_ALL`. See the php.ini file for more information on the levels and setting them.

Comment: i was using Xampp Version 1.7.4 and it used PHP 5.3.5 so when i use PHP 5.2 Joomla works fine, so i think that it is PHP roblem not Mysql as James C mentioned. So now i am using PHP 5.2

Comment: It’s not a PHP problem. PHP 5.3, by design, recommends and encourages stricter object oriented design rules/techniques. In that aspect, the E_STRICT notices also give more recommendations for better designed/implemented object oriented code.

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't look like it's to do with the database but to do with PHP's level of error reporting. I would first suggest you change the error level to exclude `E_STRICT` errors from being reported.

Comment: Check your php configuration file (php.ini) for the `error_reporting` setting.