# joomla: jomsocial installation problem (winxp)

Tags: joomla

i'm trying to install the jomsocial plugin on my local joomla.
joomla (v1.6) was freshly installed from scratch - i'm having the latest version of jomsocial (v2.20)

i've followed the jomsocial installation instructions but it didn't work,
during the installation process i got the same error over + over again:
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in ...

any ideas what could be wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted the complete error, but it looks like you need to change your php.ini error reporting log level.

See - [joomla 1.5.22 on mysql 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539710/joomla-1-5-22-on-mysql-5-5)